# cannot set iframe url programmatically

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a setIframe function to set the iframe url dynamically, but when reading back the url with getIframe url is blank why ?

index.html:

```
    <iframe id="MyIframe" src="frame.html">
    </iframe>

    <script>
    function setIframe(iframeId, url){
        document.getElementById(iframeId).src = url;
      }

      function getIframe(iframeId){
        return document.getElementById(iframeId).src;
      }


      var url = "frame.html" + location.search;
      alert(url);
      setIframe('myIframe',url);
      alert(getIframe("myIframe"));
    </script>
```

frame.html
        
          alert(location.search);

Comment: You're not returning anything from getIframe and not setting anything in setIframe

Comment: Maybe you should used something like JQuery if you can.  They already solved this problem for a bunch of browser.  Like `$('<iframe id="MyIframe" src="'+url+'"></iframe>').after('#other');`

Comment: If it is 3rd party, you can not read it, but your code does not return

Comment: it's not third party since the url is local

Comment: @Pekka that what's I observe but it doesn't explain why ?

Comment: @epascarello Even if the url is a 3rd party the only thing you can't touch is what's inside the iframe.  You can change the iframe itself however you like.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin You can not read the localtion if it is 3rd party

Comment: @epascarello What DOM property is location? I can read the "src" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `myIframe` in JavaScript but your iframe id is actually `MyIframe`, so I'm not sure how you set it up but maybe you're confused with the defined src from the element. And use `.src` instead of `.attr()`

```js
function setIframe(iframeId, url){
    document.getElementById(iframeId).src = url;
  }

  function getIframe(iframeId){
    return document.getElementById(iframeId).src;
  }

  var url = "http://gizmodo.com/";
  setIframe('MyIframe',url);
  alert(getIframe("MyIframe"));
```

```html
<iframe id="MyIframe" src="http://gizmodo.com/">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Why downvoted my answer? it's actually the issue. crazy people :(

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. The answer would include the correct code.

Comment: Did not downvoate, but that is one of the few problems with it... correcting the id is not going to fix it.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin sorry for that

Comment: @epascarello yes, but I'm just saying that the code actually works with some little tweking and answering to the problem he is getting. but what do you mean that it's not going to work if it's a third party? you mean the URL? not sure by what you mean by that

Comment: @epascarello I just tried with `<iframe id="MyIframe" src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe>` and I was able read the 'src' property and change it after the page was loaded.

Comment: @Roljhon That was not your answer when I posted that comment

Comment: @epascarello because I was editing it as I was told to put some codes :) but anyway, nevermind

Comment: I updated my code with yours (see my code update above) still I get blank after setting iframe src

Comment: @user310291 you didn't change your `id` it's still `myIframe` it should be `MyIframe`

Comment: @Roljhon allright thanks It was midnight I was sleeping :)

Answer (score 2):

`attr` is not a vanilla JS function (although it is a function in jQuery.)

You'll need to use the vanilla equivalents: `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

```
function setIframe(iframeId, url){
  document.getElementById(iframeId).setAttribute('src', url);
}

function getIframe(iframeId){
  return document.getElementById(iframeId).getAttribute('src');
}
```